# Foreach loop are displaying same rows multiple times

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a problem with my first attempt at making a foreach loop.

My problem is, that I'm only trying to call out two rows to be displayed, which kinda works, although they are being displayed as many times as there are different rows in my table.

My code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM webpages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$assoc_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

<?php foreach ($assoc_query as $value) { ?>
<tr>
   <td>
     <div id='pageimg'><img src= <?php echo $assoc_query['pic'];?>  ></div>
   </td>
   <td>
     <div id="pagename"><?php echo $assoc_query['name']; ?> </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

It's being displayed like so on the page:

```
/picture/ DAK
/picture/ DAK
/picture/ DAK
/picture/ DAK
```

Hope you can help me:)

Comment: add this code `print_r($assoc_query)` and print the result

Comment: You are using no WHERE clause in your statement, so it is only right that it shows every row. In this example that table must contain four rows with the same data in each. If you only wanted to show the first two rows of a particular result set, I suggest adding LIMIT 2 to the end of your query, along with an ORDER BY column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of foreach you will want a while. What you are doing here is looping the elements of array $assoc_query.

A while loop will get the next result set to be used.

```
while($assoc_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //Do your thing
}
```

**Also please consider updating from mysql_ to mysqli_ or PDO. What you are using is depreciated and there is added security with the newer ones.**

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. This does work, although it only shows the oldest dataset, and completely ignores the others. Any ideas?

Comment: @LauFalkeGammeljordPetersen I am not sure what you mean. This will get all the results from your query so unless your query is excluding results you should see everything.

Comment: Don't quite know whats happening, but its cutting the one with the lowest id? I've tried adding more datasets to the db, which displays just fine?

Comment: @LauFalkeGammeljordPetersen could you post your updated code.

Comment: Sure:) i posted it as an answer

Comment: @LauFalkeGammeljordPetersen you need to remove the `$assoc_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` under result it is removing your first result set.

Comment: Thanks mate you're awsome

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM webpages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$counter=0;
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $assoc_query[$counter] = $row;
    $counter++;
}

foreach ($assoc_query as $value) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='pageimg'><img src= <?php echo $value['pic'];?>  ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="pagename"><?php echo $value['name']; ?> </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this can't be done with foreach loop unless you gonna show 1 user's information only using `limit` Clause or `Where` Clause otherwise that it's useless

instead you need a while loop like this

```
<?php while ($assoc_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
   <td>
     <div id='pageimg'><img src= <?php echo $assoc_query['pic'];?>  ></div>
   </td>
   <td>
     <div id="pagename"><?php echo $assoc_query['name']; ?> </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM webpages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($assoc_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr>
   <td>
     <div id='pageimg'><img src= <?php echo $assoc_query['pic'];?>  ></div>
   </td>
   <td>
     <div id="pagename"><?php echo $assoc_query['name']; ?> </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

That should work. But as said before you shouldn't code like this. Use mysqli or PDO like nerdlyist says.

Answer (score 0):

@Nerdlyist

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM webpages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$assoc_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


<?php while ($assoc_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr>
   <td>
     <div id='pageimg'><img src= <?php echo $assoc_query['pic'];?>  ></div>
   </td>
   <td>
     <div id="pagename"><?php echo $assoc_query['name']; ?> </div>
   </td>
</tr> 
<?php } ?>
```